# How to pack a Windows EXE and its DLL in a Flet application?

Tags: windows, flet

I use `flet` CLI to package on Windows. The package depends on `unrar`, which requires the EXE and its DLL to be included in the package. My command line looks like this:

```
flet pack -D main.py -n bee --icon="E:\python\file-manager\icon\48_Goat.png" --add-data "assets\unrar.dll;." --add-data "assets\unrar.exe;."
```

When I run the exe on another Windows machine, I get the following error:

```
pyimod03_ctypes.install.<locals>.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\WDAGUtilityAccount\\Desktop\\bee\\unrar.dll'. Most likely this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
```

I confirmed the DLL can be find in the folder. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Clearly, it's not looking in `assets`